# creating a custom loop for children to use: eg. repeat(5){ //code to be executed 5 times }

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simplify the introduction of loops to children in JS and p5.js with writing some helper functions to ease difficult things. What I'm aiming for is something like `repeat(5){ //code to be executed 5 times }`

something similar can be achieved with a higher order function, but it's not quite as simple/transparent as I hope it could be.

for example:

```
function repeat(n = 1) {
  let i = 0;
  return fn => {
    while(n--) {
      i++;
      fn(i)
    }
  }
}

// example usage:
repeat(10)(i => {
  console.log('floop boop', i)
})
```

but the usage and curly/parens will confuse children. I'm aware that a while loop is one direction to go, but It's sort of goes in an inverse direction of what a repeat loop might do. It's the direction to push them, but maybe not ideal for day 1 of coding.

ultimately We could eventually use it something like:

```
let i = 0;
repeat(10){
   i++
   console.log('we are repeating and we're on iteration number ', i)
}
```

Comment: `Array(n).map(() => // code)`

Comment: This is incredibly more confusing than a basic loop

Comment: If you have lodash, there is a `_.times` method that does this. Additionally, you can use `map` or `forEach` but make sure the array is filled or it won't work. EG: `Array(100).fill(undefined).forEach(() => { /*stuff*/ })`

Comment: I must stress that anonymous functions are not day 1 material, it will confuse your students! Teach them proper foundational knowledge -- variables, conditionals, loops, functions, THEN get into the more advanced work, such as anonymous functions, etc.

Comment: You can try introducing recursion before loops if you want to go down the functional route.

Comment: I'm aware that loops are unavoidable and that they should be introduced after variables, etc., but what I'm trying to write is a function a 7 year old can use and understand immediately to do visual rendering with p5.js within a workshop setting.

Comment: The syntax you're asking for isn't possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are teaching JavaScript you won't be able to avoid first class functions. I would start by creating a method called `repeat`, it takes in a number of times to repeat and the function with the behaviour you want repeated.

```
function repeat(times, fn) {
  var i = 0;
  while(times--) {
    i++;
    fn(i);
  }
}

repeat(10, function(i) {
  console.log('we are repeating and we\'re on iteration number ', i);
});
```

I agree that a higher order function may be confusing. In both cases you don't need functions to teach loops.

Comment: you wouldn't need to teach functions right away when using something like p5.js for rendering, yes eventually, but not right away. How can we talk about the idea of loops to a group of 7 year olds in a one day workshop? having a repeat function seems like a straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Coffescript and p5.

for i in range 10
  rect 20*i,20,10,10

Range has same defintion as in underscore.

Python indentation without colon

P5dojo.com is my site.